# How to fix "Could not run graph" error when recording the screen with audio using ffmpeg in Windows 10?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to record the screen with audio using ffmpeg in Windows 10.

The following command works but it does not record the audio:

```
 .\ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop output.mkv
```

To fix the issue, first I enable Audio Mix device from control panel > sounds

[image]

and then tried to find it in my audio devices with the follwing command:

```
 .\ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

[image]

I try different syntaxes to add audio to the video in the first command:

```
.\ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 60 -video_size 1920x1080 -i desktop -f dshow -i audio="Stereo Mix (Realtek(R) Audio)" -vcodec libx264  -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -pix_fmt yuv422p -f mpegts udp://ip
   

.\ffmpeg -f gdigrab -i desktop -f dshow -i audio="Stereo Mix (Realtek(R) Audio)" -vcodec libx264 muxed-video-file.mp4
```

but the error is always the same:

```
Could not run graph (sometimes caused by a device already in use by other application)
audio=Stereo Mix (Realtek(R) Audio): I/O error
```

[image]

Please let me know if you know a working solution or a hint :-)

Comment: Your first command is fine, and works here. Use the alternative name string and check.

Comment: which alternative? I dont have any option left :-|

Comment: See the alternative name under "Stereo Mix" in the device listing.

Comment: I tried my other option "Gruppo microfoni (Tecnologia Intel® Smart Sound)", but still returns the same error

Comment: any suggestion?

Comment: Did you try the alternative name?

Comment: yes I tried "Gruppo microfoni (Tecnologia Intel® Smart Sound)", but it still returns the same error

Comment: The alternative name, not another device. See your log again.

Comment: Can you be more specific please? what is this alternative name?

Comment: If you see the log for `-list_devices` command, you will see an alternative name listed under the Stereo Mix id. Try with that.

Comment: I tried it but it does not work :-(

Comment: Are you logged on as an admin account? Try running it in cmd, not PS.

Comment: yes I am the adim. I tried the cmd but the error is the same

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured this out myself and I'm not sure if it applies in your situation but win 10 can cause virtual inputs like this to not be available due to privacy settings for the microphone.
I'm using vb-audio "virtual audio cable" but I assume the same applies to Realtek stereo mix.

For me it was fixed by going to Privacy Settings
In the App permissions section click "Microphone"
And enable "Allow apps to access your microphone"

[image: Screenshot of setting]

Comment: thanks for the answer. I see this particular setting is already set up correctly. however, I am not sure if I saw the microphone icon when I tried it. I will try again later.

Comment: Seemed to work for me; I was using Virtual Audio Cable on a windows VM and the two things I changed were: make two cables (one for line in, one for line out), and this setting. ffmpeg started working right after

Answer (score 0):

This whole time, the solution to my problem was a single button in the windows settings for a seemingly useless feature... Those VCL error messages are REALLY useless, wasted so much of my time. I'm pretty sure this is the only forum that actually mentions this as well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).